# How do I visualization generalized Pythagorean theory?

Tags: special-functions, prime-numbers, education

maybe the Pythagorean equation is not alone. can't this equation be just one element of an array
like this for example.
exponents must be prime numbers (otherwise it's just a combination of other elements)

first elment a^2+b^2=c^2 (this is Pythagoras)
second element a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3 ( but I can't visualize it in the coordinate system like Pythagoras equation)
thirth element a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5=f^5
fourth element a^7+b^7+c^7...et

Comment: Yes there are integers with: n=3. The smallest are: 3^3+ 4^3+ 5^3==6^3; They are called "Fermat cubics". There are also solutions for n=4,5,6,...

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To bound the problem let `1 <= {a, b, c} <= 100` and to avoid equivalent results that are just reorderings of `{a, b, c}` let `{a, b, c}` be ordered such that  `a <= b <= c <= 100`,

```
(inst = Select[
    Flatten[
     Table[{a, b, c, Norm[{a, b, c}, 3]},
      {a, 1, 100}, {b, a, 100}, {c, b, 100}],
     2],
    IntegerQ@Last@# &]) // Length

(* 98 *)
```

Verifying,

```
And @@ (Total[Most[#]^3] == Last[#]^3 & /@ inst)

(* True *)
```

Looking at the first five and last five instances,

```
TableForm[inst[[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98}]], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {a, b, c, d}},
 TableAlignments -> {Right, Center}]
```

[image]

```
{dmin, dmax} = MinMax[inst[[All, 4]]]

(* {6, 139} *)
```

Plotting,

```
Legended[
 ListPointPlot3D[Most /@ inst,
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {a, b, c}),
  ColorFunction -> Function[{a, b, c},
    ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[Norm[{a, b, c}, 3],
      {dmin, dmax}]]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False],
 BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {dmin, dmax}},
  LegendLabel -> Style[d, 14]]]
```

[image]